# Use reduce to sum all values of an array passed via a console log

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the total of an array passed via a console log. However instead of adding the numbers it's returning the array with a 0 in front.

This is what I have tried

```js
const sum2 = (array) => {
  let total = 0;
  const totalFigure = array.reduce((total, number) => {}, 0)
  return total + array
}

console.log(sum2([1, 3, 5, 7, 9]));
```

Comment: I think you need to look into how [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) works.

Comment: That's cuz you're using it wrong. Try: `const totalFigure = array.reduce((total, number) => total + number, 0)`

Comment: Your sytax is issue: 
const sum2 = (array) => {
       return array.reduce((previousValue, currentValue)  => 
         { 
          return previousValue+currentValue
         }
       );
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.prototype.reduce()` accepts callback function where the first parameter of the callback is "total" value calculated in previous iteration of loop and current value of iteration as the second parameter. The final code could look like this:

```js
const sum2 = arr => {
  const result = arr.reduce((total, number) => {
    return total + number;
  }, 0);

  return result;
};
```

And shorter:

```js
const sum2 = arr => arr.reduce((total, number) => total + number, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not doing anything to reduce your array in that function

```
(total, number) => {}
```

and your initial value is 0, you are just adding 0 to your array by returning

```
total + array
```

You are never summing up your array. `total + array` turns into `0 + array.toString()` which creates the `01,3,5,7,9` you are seeing.

If you want to sum up the values of you array, this is one approach:

```js
const sum2 = (array) => array.reduce((total, number) => total+=number, 0)

console.log(sum2([1, 3, 5, 7, 9]));
```

```
(total, number) => total+=number
```

this increments the initial value (which `total` is first set to) by `number`, adding them together and returning them to the next iteration of the reduce function

Comment: It doesn't have to be `total += number`. It can be `total + number`.

Comment: @Andy you're right ofc, I feel personally it's easier to understand, but both works.